# Confusing Inverse Function Problem

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm trying to find the inverse of the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 1}{ x}$. I know that it's not fully inversible, but it should be on a smaller scope, but I just couldn't do it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What about telling us what you tried so far, so we can help you based on that?

Comment: Sketching the graph of the function should help you find a domain restriction where the function is invertible.

Comment: Set $y = \frac{x^2 - 1}x$, then solve for $x$. Start by multiplying through by $x$ to get rid of the denominator. Then move the $yx$ term to the other side. You end up with a quadratic equation in $x$. Solve that equation, restrict the domain of the inverse to those values of $y$ where the square root is not of a negative number, and choose which branch you are going to use as your inverse value.